I'm trying to integrate webRTC video call in react native but remote stream appears black
I'm trying to integrate a webRTC video call in react native using socket.io for the data transmission system, but the remote stream appears black for both users while the local stream works well. I don't know if the issue is caused by the iceCandidate but it's not just working. This is my integration below
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef, MutableRefObject} from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Keyboard,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import TextInputContainer from '@/components/TextInputContainer';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
import {
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCView,
  mediaDevices,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  MediaStream,
} from "react-native-webrtc";
import EventEmitter from 'react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter';

const socket = io("http://192.168.54.158:4000")

const configuration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: ["stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302", "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302"],
    },
  ],
};

export default function App({}) {

  const [type, setType] = useState('JOIN');

  const [callerId] = useState(
    Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000).toString(),
  );
  const [userToCall, setUserToCall] = useState("")
  const [callerOffer, setCallerOffer] = useState<any | null>(null)
  const [calleeAnswer, setCalleeAnswer] = useState<any | null>(null)
  const [incomingCallerId, setIncomingCallerId] = useState("")
  const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState<MediaStream | null>()
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState<MediaStream | null>()
  const [cachedLocalPC, setCachedLocalPC] = useState<RTCPeerConnection | null>(null)
  const [iceCandidates, setIceCandidates] = useState<RTCIceCandidate[]>([])
  // const pc = useRef<RTCPeerConnection>()

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleConnectToSocket = () => { 
      socket.connect()
      socket.on("myid", (data) => {
        console.log(data)
      })
      console.log('About to connect')

      socket.emit("registerUser", { userId: callerId })

      socket.on("callUser", (data) => {
        const { from, signal, name } = data
        setType("INCOMING_CALL")
        setIncomingCallerId(from)
        setCallerOffer(signal)
        console.log("completing setting offer")
      })
      socket.on("rejectCall", ({ signal }) => {
        console.log("call rejected")
        setType("JOIN")
      } )
      socket.on("iceCandidate", ({ candidate }) => {
        console.log("Added candidate ICE list from useEffect listener")
        const newIceCandidate = [...iceCandidates, candidate]
        setIceCandidates(newIceCandidate)
      })
    }
    handleConnectToSocket()
    startLocalStream()

  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(localStream, `This is the local stream ${callerId}`)
    console.log(remoteStream, `This is the remote stream ${callerId}`)
  }, [localStream, remoteStream])

  const startLocalStream = async () => {
    // isFront will determine if the initial camera should face user or environment
    const isFront = true;
    const devices = await mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

    const facing = isFront ? "front" : "environment";
    // @ts-ignore
    const videoSourceId = devices.find(
      (device: any) => device.kind === "videoinput" && device.facing === facing
    );
    const facingMode = isFront ? "user" : "environment";
    const constraints = {
      audio: true,
      video: {
        mandatory: {
          minWidth: 500, // Provide your own width, height and frame rate here
          minHeight: 300,
          minFrameRate: 30,
        },
        facingMode,
        optional: videoSourceId ? [{ sourceId: videoSourceId }] : [],
      },
    };
    const newStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    setLocalStream(newStream);
  };

  const handleCallOtherUser = async () => {

    const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration)
    if(localStream === undefined || localStream === null) {
      console.log("Local stream does not exist unable to proceed with call")
      return
    }
    localStream?.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });
    peerConnection.addEventListener("icecandidate", (event) => {
      if(!event.candidate) {
        console.log(`Got last candidate`)
        return
      }
      socket.emit("iceCandidate", { to: userToCall, candidate: event?.candidate })
      console.log('candidate emitted to callee')
    })
    peerConnection.addEventListener("iceconnectionstatechange", (event) => {
      console.log(peerConnection.iceConnectionState, "connection state")
    })

    peerConnection.addEventListener("track", (event) => {
      const newStream = new MediaStream()
      event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track: any) => {
        newStream.addTrack(track)
      })
      console.log(`added a new track to the remote caller`)
      setRemoteStream(newStream)
    })

    // @ts-ignore
    const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);

    socket.on("iceCandidate", ({ candidate }) => {
      if(!peerConnection.remoteDescription) {
        console.log("no remote description so stored ice candidate")
        const newIceCandidate = [...iceCandidates, candidate]
        setIceCandidates(newIceCandidate)
      } else {
        peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))
      }
    })

    socket.on("callAccepted", ({ signal }) => {
      console.log(`Call accepted`)
      if(!signal) {
        console.log(`No answer received`)
        return
      }
      if(!peerConnection.remoteDescription) {
        console.log(`No remote descirption so will add answer`)
        const remoteAnswer = new RTCSessionDescription(signal)
        peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(remoteAnswer)
      } else {
        console.log("Setting remote stream to null")
        setRemoteStream(null)
      }
      // dependent on wether to set ice candidate here or not
      if(iceCandidates && iceCandidates.length > 0) {
        iceCandidates.forEach((candidate: any) => {
          console.log("Added a candidate")
          peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))
        })
        console.log(`added candidates for caller`)
      }
      setType("CALL")
    })
    socket.emit("callUser", { from: callerId, name: callerId, userToCall: userToCall,  signalData: offer })
    setType("OUTGOING_CALL")

    setCachedLocalPC(peerConnection)
  }

  const handleAcceptCall = async () => {

    const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration)

    if(localStream === undefined || localStream === null) {
      console.log("Local stream does not exist unable to pick call")
      return
    }

    localStream?.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      peerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream);
    });

    peerConnection.addEventListener("icecandidate", (event) => {
      if(!event.candidate) {
        console.log(`Got last candidate`)
        return
      }
      socket.emit("iceCandidate", { to: incomingCallerId, candidate: event?.candidate })
      console.log('candidate emitted to caller')
    })
    peerConnection.addEventListener("iceconnectionstatechange", (event) => {
      console.log(peerConnection.iceConnectionState, "connection state")
    })

    peerConnection.addEventListener("track", (event) => {
      const newStream = new MediaStream()
      event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach((track: any) => {
        newStream.addTrack(track)
      })
      console.log(`added a new track to the remote callee`)
      setRemoteStream(newStream)
    })

    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(callerOffer))

    const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer()
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer)

    socket.emit("answerCall", { to: incomingCallerId, signal: answer })

    socket.on("iceCandidate", ({ candidate }) => {
      console.log("caller received ice candidate from callee")
      if(!peerConnection.remoteDescription) {
        const newIceCandidate = [...iceCandidates, candidate]
        setIceCandidates(newIceCandidate)
      } else {
        console.log("candidate added after remote description")
        peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))
      }
    })
    
    if(iceCandidates && iceCandidates.length > 0) {
      iceCandidates.forEach((candidate: any) => {
        console.log("Added a candidate")
        peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))
      })
      console.log(`added candidates for callee`)
    }
    setType("CALL")

  }

  const handleRejectCall = () => {
    setType("JOIN")
    socket.emit("rejectCall", { to: incomingCallerId, signal: callerOffer })
  }

  const JoinScreen = () => {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#050A0E',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          paddingHorizontal: 42,
        }}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <>
            <View
              style={{
                padding: 35,
                backgroundColor: '#1A1C22',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                borderRadius: 14,
              }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: '#D0D4DD',
                }}>
                Your Caller ID 
              </Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  marginTop: 12,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 32,
                    color: '#ffff',
                    letterSpacing: 6,
                  }}>
                  {callerId}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>

            <View
              style={{
                backgroundColor: '#1A1C22',
                padding: 40,
                marginTop: 25,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                borderRadius: 14,
              }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: '#D0D4DD',
                }}>
                Enter call id of another user
              </Text>
              <TextInputContainer
                placeholder={'Enter Caller ID'}
                value={userToCall}
                setValue={setUserToCall}
                keyboardType={'number-pad'}
              />
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={handleCallOtherUser}
                style={{
                  height: 50,
                  backgroundColor: '#5568FE',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  borderRadius: 12,
                  marginTop: 16,
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                  }}>
                  Call Now
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  };

  const OutgoingCallScreen = () => {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#050A0E',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          paddingHorizontal: 42,
        }}>
          <View
              style={{
                padding: 35,
                backgroundColor: '#1A1C22',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                borderRadius: 14,
              }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: '#D0D4DD',
                }}>
                You are calling
              </Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  marginTop: 12,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 32,
                    color: '#ffff',
                    letterSpacing: 6,
                  }}>
                  {userToCall}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                backgroundColor: '#1A1C22',
                padding: 40,
                marginTop: 25,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                borderRadius: 14,
              }}>
              <View
                style={{
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center'
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: '#D0D4DD',
                  }}>
                  Ringing...
                </Text>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  setType('JOIN');
                }}
                style={{
                  height: 50,
                  backgroundColor: '#5568FE',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  borderRadius: 12,
                  marginTop: 16,
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                  }}>
                  Hang up
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  };

  const IncomingCallScreen = () => {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#050A0E',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          paddingHorizontal: 42,
        }}>
          <View
              style={{
                padding: 35,
                backgroundColor: '#1A1C22',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                borderRadius: 14,
              }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: '#D0D4DD',
                }}>
                Incoming Call from
              </Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  marginTop: 12,
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 32,
                    color: '#ffff',
                    letterSpacing: 6,
                  }}>
                  {incomingCallerId}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                backgroundColor: '#1A1C22',
                padding: 40,
                marginTop: 25,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                borderRadius: 14,
              }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={handleAcceptCall}
                style={{
                  height: 50,
                  backgroundColor: '#5568FE',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  borderRadius: 12,
                  marginTop: 16,
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                  }}>
                  Accept Call
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={handleRejectCall}
                style={{
                  height: 50,
                  backgroundColor: '#5568FE',
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  borderRadius: 12,
                  marginTop: 16,
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                  }}>
                  Reject Call
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  };
  

  switch (type) {
    case 'JOIN':
      return JoinScreen();
    case 'INCOMING_CALL':
      return IncomingCallScreen();
    case 'OUTGOING_CALL':
      return OutgoingCallScreen();
    case 'CALL':
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#050A0E',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            paddingHorizontal: 12,
          }}>
          {localStream && <RTCView
            streamURL={localStream && localStream.toURL()}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#1A1C22",
              height: "45%",
              flex: 0.5
            }}
            objectFit='cover'
          />}
          {remoteStream ? (<RTCView
            streamURL={remoteStream && remoteStream.toURL()}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
              height: "45%",
              padding: 25,
              flex: 0.4,
              borderRadius: 20
            }}
            objectFit='cover'
          />) : (<Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>There is no remote stream</Text>)}
          {remoteStream  && (
            <View>
              <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>
                Dey play o remote stream dey!
              </Text>
            </View>
          )}
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleRejectCall}
            style={{
              height: 50,
              backgroundColor: '#5568FE',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
              borderRadius: 12,
              marginTop: 16,
            }}>
            <Text>
              End Call
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )
    default:
      return null;
  }
}

// Backend Integration
import { Server, Socket } from "socket.io";
import http from 'http';

interface ServerToClientEvents {
    myid: (data: { socketId: string }) => void;
    callEnded: (data: { message: string }) => void;
    callUser: (data: { signal: any, from: string, name: string }) => void;
    callAccepted: (data: { signal: any }) => void;
    callRejected: (data: { signal: any }) => void;
    iceCandidate: (data: { candidate: any }) => void;
}
  
interface ClientToServerEvents {
    registerUser: (data: { userId: string }) => void;
    callUser: (data: { userToCall: string, signalData: any, from: string, name: string }) => void;
    answerCall: (data: { to: string, signal: any }) => void;
    rejectCall: (data: { to: string, signal: any }) => void;
    iceCandidate: (data: { to: string, candidate: any }) => void;
}

interface InterServerEvents {}
  
interface SocketData {}

const createSocketServer = (httpServer: http.Server) => {
    const io = new Server<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents, InterServerEvents, SocketData>(httpServer)
    const userSocketMap: { [key: string]: string } = {}
    io.on("connection", (socket: Socket<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents, InterServerEvents, SocketData>): void => {
        console.log(`connected to socket id: ${socket.id}`)
        // socket.emit("myid", { socketId: socket.id })

        socket.on("callUser", (data) => {
            const { userToCall, signalData, from, name } = data
            console.log(`tried to call user`)
            console.log(userSocketMap[userToCall], "User to call")
            io.to(userSocketMap[userToCall]).emit("callUser", { signal: signalData, from: from, name: name })
        })

        socket.on("registerUser", (data) => {
            const { userId } = data;
            userSocketMap[userId] = socket.id;
            console.log(`User ${userId} registered with socket id: ${socket.id}`);
            console.log(userSocketMap, "User Socket Map")
        });

        socket.on("answerCall", (data) => {
            const { to, signal } = data;
            io.to(userSocketMap[to]).emit("callAccepted", { signal: signal });
        });

        socket.on("rejectCall", (data) => {
            const { to, signal } = data
            io.to(userSocketMap[to]).emit("callRejected", { signal: signal })
        })

        socket.on("iceCandidate", (data) => {
            const { to, candidate } = data;
            console.log(`new candidate to ${to}`, candidate)
            io.to(userSocketMap[to]).emit("iceCandidate", { candidate: candidate });
        });

        socket.on("disconnect", () => {
            for (const userId in userSocketMap) {
              if (userSocketMap[userId] === socket.id) {
                delete userSocketMap[userId];
                break;
              }
            }
        })

    })

    return io
}

export default createSocketServer

I've tried different formats following the flow on the MDN web docs, but I don't know why it's not working, I've checked the flow multiple times and I ensured that the flow was strictly followed.
